# What is the return type of a custom render for extending React Testing Library in test-utils using React/Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, function, react-testing-library, react-typescript

I'm not sure of the return type for the custom render function that uses Render of React Testing Library, I would've assumed it was element or JSX but that doesn't seem to work.

Code:

```
import React, { ReactElement } from 'react'
import { render, RenderOptions } from '@testing-library/react'
import { theme } from './theme'
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { searchReducer, initialState } from './store/reducer/searchReducer'

const store = createStore(searchReducer, initialState)

interface ProviderProps { 
  children?: NonNullable<React.ReactNode>
}

const TheProvider: React.FC<ProviderProps> = ({
  children,
}) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        { children }
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Provider>
  )
}

// here is the issue for function return type
const customRender= (
  ui: ReactElement,
  options?: Omit<RenderOptions, 'queries'>
) => render(ui, { wrapper: TheProvider, ...options })

export * from '@testing-library/react'

export { customRender as render }
```

Comment: It should implicitly return the same type as the `render` function from `@testing-library/react`.

Comment: that is what I assumed, however my customerRender function props have a warning of 'missing return type of function,' and when I give the function the return type 'typeof render,' it errors;

Type 'RenderResult<typeof import("/path/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/types/queries"), HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type '{ <Q extends Queries = typeof import("/path/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/types/queries"),

Answer (score 7):

> when I give the function the return type `typeof render`, it errors; Type 'RenderResult<typeof import("/path/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/types/queries"), HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type '{ <Q extends Queries = typeof import("/path/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/types/queries")

The return type of `customRender` would be `ReturnType<typeof render>` instead of just `typeof render`.  That works, but you don't need to use `typeof` because you can import the correct type from the React Testing Library package.  The type you want is `RenderResult`.

```
import { render, RenderOptions, RenderResult } from '@testing-library/react'
```

```
const customRender = (
  ui: ReactElement,
  options?: Omit<RenderOptions, "queries">
): RenderResult =>
  render(ui, { wrapper: TheProvider, ...options });
```